# Comments not showing when page is inserted with ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

The comment system in showpost.html works fine when I navigate to it as a separate page, but when including showpost.html in post.html using ng-include the comments aren't showing for me.  Anyone see any nesting or scope issues that I'm not catching?

The controllers for these are located in app.js, and it's not detecting that I'm signed in // ng-hide="signedIn()" in showpost.html // because the comment textarea shows up when I sign out.  So ng-show and ng-hide are doing the opposite of what I expect when I include the page.

posts.html

```
<div class="ui comments">
  <h3 class="ui dividing header">Latest posts</h3>

  <div class="comment" ng-repeat="post in posts">
    <a class="ui avatar image">
      <img src="/images/avatar/guy.jpg">
    </a>
    <div class="content">
      <a class="author"><a ng-href="#/users/{{ post.creatorUID }}"><b>{{ post.creator }}</b></a></span></a>
      <div class="metadata">
        <span class="date">Yesterday at 12:30AM</span>
      </div>
      <a ng-click="deletePost(post)" ng-show="user.uid === post.creatorUID" class="close-post"><i class="blue remove circle icon large"></i></a>
        <div>
            <a ng-href="{{ post.url }}">
            {{ post.title }}</a><br><br>
            <span class="url">{{ post.url | hostnameFromUrl }}</span>
            <br><br>
        </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <a class="reply" ng-href="#/posts/{{ post.$id }}">Add comment...</a>
      </div>
    </div><br>


<!-- COMMENTS NESTED -->

  <div ng-include src="'views/showpost.html'"></div>

<!-- COMMENTS NESTED -->

  </div>
</div>
```

showpost.html (the comments page)

```
<div class="container posts-page"> 
    <div ng-repeat="comment in comments" class="row cmt">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>{{ comment.text }}</p>
            <p class="author">posted by <a ng-href="#/profile/{{ comment.creatorUID }}">{{ comment.creator }}</a>
            <a ng-href="#/posts/{{ post.$id }}" ng-click="deleteComment(comment, $index)" ng-show="signedIn() && comment.creatorUID === user.uid">(delete)</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cmt-form">
        <div ng-hide="signedIn()">
            <p><a href="#/login">Sign in</a> to post a comment</p>
        </div>

        <form ng-show="signedIn()" ng-submit="addComment()">
            <textarea ng-model="commentText" placeholder="Post a Comment" class="form-control"></textarea><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Post Comment" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </form>
    </div>

</div>
```

app.js

```
/* global app:true */
/* exported app */
/* 'Firebase': false */

'use strict';

var app = angular
  .module('devNews', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'firebase'
  ])

  .constant('FIREBASE_URL', 'https://sweltering-heat-8723.firebaseio.com/')

  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/posts.html',
        controller: 'PostsCtrl'
      })
      .when('/posts/:postId', {
        templateUrl: 'views/showpost.html',
        controller: 'PostViewCtrl'
      })
      .when('/register', {
        templateUrl: 'views/register.html',
        controller: 'AuthCtrl',
        // Resolve authentication of user before redirecting
        resolve: {
          // Define user property to inject into controller
          user: function(Auth) {
            return Auth.resolveUser();
          }
        }
      })
      .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
        controller: 'AuthCtrl', 
        resolve: {
          user: function(Auth) {
            return Auth.resolveUser();
          }
        }
      })
      .when('/users/:userId', {
        templateUrl: 'views/profile.html',
        controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```